# How does the Whitehead quadratic functor act on morphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, finite-groups

I am trying to understand the universal quadratic functor $\Gamma$ that appears on the Whitehead exact sequence (J. Whitehead, *A certain exact sequence*, Annals of Mathematics **52** (1950)) particularly in the context of finite groups. It has some known properties as

- $\Gamma(\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}$,
- $\Gamma(\mathbb{Z}_n)=\mathbb{Z}_n$, if $n$ is odd,
- $\Gamma(\mathbb{Z}_n)=\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$, if $n$ is even,
- $\Gamma(A\oplus B) = \Gamma(A)\oplus \Gamma(B) \oplus (A\otimes B)$,
- If the multiplication by $n$, $\cdot n\colon A\to A$ is an isomorphism, then $\Gamma(\cdot n)=\cdot n^2\colon \Gamma(A)\to \Gamma(A)$ is an isomorphism as well.

but in general papers where they work with it do not state how it works over morphisms, other that it takes automorphisms to automorphisms. I am trying to figure out how it works over finite groups. For instance, suppose that we have the group $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$, so from the properties above we get that $\Gamma(\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2)$ is $\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus \mathbb{Z}_4\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$. Now take the automorphism $f$ of $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ given by $f(x,y)=(x+y,x)$. Then $f^3=id$, so $\Gamma(f)$ must either be of degree three in the group of automorphisms or the identity. However, I really do not see a natural way of defining $\Gamma(f)$, which should actually be posible since they usually omit the definition of the functor on morphism. What am I missing? What is $\Gamma(f)$ in this case?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Baues `Homotopy type and Homology' on p. 15. The idea is to use the homomorphism $f:A\to B$ together with the universal quadratic map
$\gamma:B\to \Gamma(B)$ to get a quadratic map from $A$ to $B$ which factorises via $\Gamma(A)$.